# Does a null check in Java take any significant amount of time?

Tags: java, null

In Java, how long does a null check take?

```
if(someBigObject == null) //How long does this take?
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't be null!");
```

Is about about the same as saying `i = 1`? Does it depend on the size of the object, or is that irrelevant because it checks a pointer instead of the actual value?

Basically the reason I ask is that I have a loop that deals with large objects and needs to run as fast as possible, and I'm wondering if doing a null check on each iteration will have any significant effect.

Comment: What do you do in case of object not null? Most probably the check is negligible w.r.t to that.

Comment: It takes as much time as any other basic, low-level conditional.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ok, and is that because it's checking a pointer instead of the actual value?

Comment: @NiVeR then I proceed to use it in a variety of operations

Comment: How could it depend on the size of the object? Either there is no object at all because the reference is null, or there is an object, and this the reference is not null, whatever it's referencing. So the answer is: a null check is extremely cheap.

Comment: Its fast, a single bytecode operand "ifnonnull".

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to properly profile your code to determine where the actual hotspots of performance are.  Chasing something like this isn't going to produce much in the way of value.

Comment: Oh boy. Don't do performance optimizations by guessing what you think takes a long time. Even people waay more experienced than you seem to be (as in: have a good idea what the code here gets compiled to) get that wrong 9 out of 10 times. Profile, profile, profile. If your conditional takes up a measurable amount of time in your profiling then you can come back and worry about this (you'll never will).

Comment: If it's not supposed to be null then don't check for null.  A NullPointerException will be thrown and a misbehaving client will have to fix it.

Comment: @JBNizet well, if it's checking the pointer, then it wouldn't be dependent on the size of the object. But if it's checking the actual object then it could be dependent on the size.

Comment: @AndroidDev A null check is _always_ on a reference. Not sure what you mean about _checking the actual object_.

Comment: @AndroidDev But it's not checking the object. It's only checking if the reference variable has a null reference.

Comment: @GriffeyDog *"A null check is always on a reference"* well ok, but I didn't know that :)

Comment: @AndroidDev you don't seem to understand what null means. Again, a variable has the value null when it doesn't reference any object. So, if it references an object, whatever the size of the object is, it's not null.

Comment: Short answer: it takes virtually no time.  It’s literally comparing a pointer value to zero.  One or two assembly instructions.  On a modern CPU with predictive branching, the execution time may not even be measurable.

Comment: @VGR thanks, that's the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: predictive branching isn't magic, but it gets pretty close. @AndroidDev if you are worried about things being null or not null, I'd recommend using annotations, and avoiding null at all costs. Mind you, using optionals in place of nulls is likely less performant, but it will result in code that's easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

If you check a simple value for a branch you never take, the CPU can use branch prediction to almost eliminate the cost. Ie the cost is likely to be sub nanosecond.

I would profile the cost with a realistic input before making micro optimizations.